# My custom converter not getting triggered

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to introduce a custom converter for conversion Set of Object --> Object. In my web tier i will get comma (',') separated String with the domain object keys.

For example

If DB record are as shown below for table Names

id Name

1   a

2   b

and i have the associated domain object for the table. From web tier i get 1,2 string which is bind to my DTO as an array of my domain objects.

In this case i see the default Spring converter String to Array of Objects taking precedence over my custom converter and causing an array of my domain objects created with empty domain objects.

But, i want my converter to be executed which gets the domain objects based on ID from DB.

How can i force my converter to be executed in first place to Spring default converters.

PS: I made the conversion target object to be Object rather than my Domain object because i want this to be generic and should work for all my domain objects.

I am not using mvc:annotation-driven and we have expanded that manually as needed.

---

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.shivaji" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
  </context:component-scan>

  <bean class="com.shivaji.mvc.request.shivajiRequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
        <property name="conversionService" ref="applicationConversionService" />
        <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="conversionServiceExposingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.ConversionServiceExposingInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg ref="applicationConversionService" />
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="applicationConversionService">
    <property name="converters">
      <set>
        <bean class="com.shivaji.converter.DateToStringConverter">
          <property name="pattern" value="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS" />
        </bean>
      </set>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Support auto conversion -->
  <bean class="com.shivaji.converter.auto.AutoEntityToIdConverterBeanFactory" />
  <bean class="com.shivaji.converter.auto.AutoIdToEntityConverterBeanFactory" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.mapping.support.ConversionMapperFactory" id="conversionMapperFactory" autowire="byType" />
```